# Calling a script from a web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

How could I call this script within a Web Service? I've already made the link i just need a point in the right direction for the code as I've never done anything with web services before.

```
namespace WebServiceTranslator
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private Dictionary<string, string> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase); 

            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:/dictionary.csv")))
                {
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        string[] tokens = reader.ReadLine().Split(';');
                        _dictionary[tokens[0]] = tokens[1];
                    }
                }
            }


            public string Translate(string input)
            {
                string output;
                if (_dictionary.TryGetValue(input, out output))
                    return output;
                throw new Exception("There is no meaning for this");
            }


    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want to "call the above code", through a webservice?

Comment: @LouisvanTonder yes, if this is possible (make it run as a web service)

Comment: Sure is, but its a bit broad to explain web services as an answer. You should look into basic webservices howto's. In a nutshell, your webservice will eventually run at a "url". You will reference this URL as the service address when creating a service reference to the webservice from your code. You can then make calls to the methods exposed on the webservice (IE, call your code that should be exposed in your webservice through a method.) See this _> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301273

Comment: @LouisvanTonder the code above is from a web form running in the web service and it has a service reference for the address Im just not entirely sure how to make the calls to the webservice from the code

Comment: Your webservice cant be a "form"... (someone correct me?). Your webservice exposes methods, and on a separate / remote form, you create a reference to the webservice, and call its methods through this reference.

Comment: The link I added above has a great, basic example of a webservice, and how to "consume" it.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into basic webservices howto's.

In a nutshell, your webservice will eventually run at a "url". You will reference this URL as the service address when creating a service reference to the webservice from your code. You can then make calls to the methods exposed on the webservice (IE, call your code that should be exposed in your webservice through a method.)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301273

Your webservice exposes methods, and on a separate / remote form, you create a reference to the webservice, and call its methods through this reference.

Create a reference to your webservice by right clicking on your project, and choosing "Add Service Reference". You the specify the details on where your webservice is, and you get a reference to the webservice.

```
Dim myWebService as new WebserviceReferenceAdded
myWebService.<method>
```